# Telnet not working for a specific process

Tags: process, telnet, port

I have etcd process running on serverA on port 2379. I am trying to telnet to serverA from serverB and its showing connection refused.

```
# telnet <IP_serverA> 2379
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

troubleshoot steps:--

1. In the serverA the app is up and running on the port, i could see that the telnet to localhost 2379 is connecting
2. I stopped the current process(etcd) using the port and started a dummy app using

   ```
    python3 -m http.server 2379
   ```

and after this, I was able to connect to serverA from serverB. What am i missing here and why am i not able to telnet when the desired app(etcd) is running on that port?

Comment: Is you application listening on the external interface, or only on localhost? Can you connect to it from the server it's running on, using its public ip?

Comment: With your `etcd` running, please add output of `netstat -nap | grep -w 2379` (run as root) to your question.

Comment: ETCD was running on localhost. Thanks for pointing it out.